# C++ std::array to vector of shared_ptr

Tags: c++, pointers, containers, shared-ptr, smart-pointers

What is the most idiomatic way to convert it?

```
std::array<SomeType,SIZE> arr;

std::vector<shared_ptr<SomeType>> vec;  // <--- want to fill with pointers
                                        //      to items in arr
```

Second question - is it possible to create a `shared_ptr` to objects in a **stack-allocated** `array` ? Will the pointer targets be "freed" once `vec` is destroyed?

**EDIT**

I need something like this

```
class Element {
  Element *next;
}

class Group {
  std::vector<Element*> elems;
}

int main() {
  ...

  std::array<Element,10> elems = {...};
  std::array<Group,4> groups = {...};

  // shuffle elems and assign to groups; set next-pointers in elems:
  //  group1: &elem10
  //  group2: &elem8 &elem5
  //  group3: &elem2 &elem7 &elem3
  //  group4: &elem4 &elem9 &elem1 &elem6

  // at some point:
  //  save or load all elems and groups,
  //  preserving pointers elem->elem, group->elem
}
```

Comment: do you mind if the objects in `arr` are moved-from or copied?

Comment: @RichardHodges I think OP wants pointers to items inside `arr`, not pointer to object that are copy of objects in `arr`.

Comment: What do you mean by "freeing" the pointer targets? You cannot "free" non-dynamically allocated memory.

Comment: @Holt Yes, you're right, I want pointers to items _inside_ `arr`. I thought the freeing was done by `shared_ptr` when refcount becomes zero, regardless of where the referenced object resides. Does the `shared_ptr` know that the object is not heap allocated?

Comment: What you want is a non-owning pointer, ie. a raw pointer or a std::reference_wrapper

Comment: @boofaz The `shared_ptr` does not care how the object was allocated, it only knows that the deleter must be called when the refcount becomes zero. WIth default deleter, you will get a call to `delete` (or `delete[]`), but since you will be pointing to local variable, this will crash. What do you want to free here? Maybe show a more complete example...

Comment: What's your actual use case?

Comment: Why do you need the array and the vector? Why not use the vector by itself in the first place?

Comment: @Holt That's the point. I want to use a (smart) pointer, but not free anything. That's why I'm unsure whether this would be possible using a smart pointer. Maybe I have to use a different type of smart pointer?

Comment: @boofaz It's possible but I cannot see the use case... What would you want a smart pointer if you point to locally allocated stuff? What not use normal pointer or `std::ref`?

Comment: @Pandatyr I want to shuffle pointers to elements in the array without modifying the array itself. These pointers would then be stored in a number of vectors.

Comment: @Holt Well, I was under the impression that raw pointers are a no-no. Didn't know about `std::ref`.

Comment: @boofaz Raw pointers are not no-no if you know what you are doing... If you know that the vectors are never going to outlive the original array, then using raw pointers or `std::ref` (which are raw pointer in disguise) is ok. In this case, you could also simply shuffle an array of index if you don't want to mess with pointers / references.

Comment: *Owning* raw pointers are generally considered bad. Since std::array doesn't manage dynamic memory ownership isn't a concern in the first place.

Comment: So that basically means I cannot create a `shared_ptr` of a stack-allocated object? I need this for serialization using Cereal, which cannot handle raw pointers.

Comment: @boofaz You can, you just need to pass an empty deleter, e.g. `std::shared_ptr(&arr[i], [](SomeType *) { });`, seems strange that you need a `shared_ptr` to serialize though...

Comment: @Holt I believe at that point he might as well use `unique_ptr` as well and save himself the overhead `shared_ptr` entails (provided copying the smart pointers isn't needed)

Comment: @Pandatyr It is needed. They will be in multiple places. I'll try `std::ref` with Cereal, maybe that will work.

Comment: @boofaz Show us what you want to do with Cereal, it'll be easier to help if we can see the whole picture.

Answer (score 3):

If you want a `shared_ptr` to an object, then you should ensure that the object really is managed by a `shared_ptr`.  Playing games with this is dangerous and can lead to undefined behaviour.  In your case, the trick is to manage the array itself with a `shared_ptr`.  That will let you retrieve a valid `shared_ptr` to any of its elements.

```
auto elems = std::make_shared<std::array<Element,10>>();
```

You can then use `shared_ptr`'s aliasing constructor to create `shared_ptrs` to the individual elements.  If you want to stick those `shared_ptrs` in a `vector`, you could do something like this:

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Element>> v;
v.reserve(elems->size());

std::transform(
  elems->begin(),
  elems->end(),
  std::back_inserter(v),
  [&elems] (Element& e) { return std::shared_ptr<Element>{ elems, &e }; });
```

Note that one (possibly unintended) consequence of this is that your entire elements array will continue to exist as long as you have a `shared_ptr` to one of its members.

Comment: Right answer, but the op is unlikely to know why. +1